# Why does block element inside inline one cause appearing of extra vertical space?

Tags: html, css

I encountered some surprising rendering rules while working with a web framework.

```css
app-custom-element {
    margin-right: 1em;
}

button {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <app-custom-element>
        <div>Hello</div>
    </app-custom-element>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

As long as `app-custom-element` preserves its inline nature the empty space between it and the button crops up (or inside it). What is the space and how its height calculated?

But there is another thing. If we remove the `margin-right`, the space would dissapear, even though the `app-custom-element` is still an inline element. So what's the way margins affect such behavior?

Comment: add a small padding and border to your inline element to see what is happening and check the duplicate for the full explanation